# Possible to make HttpClient call with managed identity?

Tags: c#, rest, azure-devops

I am trying to make rest calls with my PAT/access token (in Azure) and it works.

```
public static async void GetProjects()
{
    try
    {
        var personalaccesstoken = "PAT_FROM_WEBSITE";

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                Convert.ToBase64String(
                    System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                        string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", personalaccesstoken))));

            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(
                        "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/projects"))
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

I want to make http call with managed identity though. Is it possible ? If yes then how ?

Answer (score 0):

If the target supports AAD auth, you can use MSI to authenticate.  You simply fetch an access token for the target scope.  See eg [Managed Identities - Connect to Azure services in app code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=portal%2Chttp#connect-to-azure-services-in-app-code)

Comment: In my REST Call, I want the managed identity. REST Call only supports Basic and Bearer/Access Token Auth. I can authenticate with MSI but when I do REST Call, I again need to send authenticate request right ?

Comment: You add an authentication header with the bearer token retrieved from the MSI endpoint.

Comment: I was thinking there is no bearer token for managed identity. MSI does the managed identity and even gives access token ?

Comment: MSI enables a localhost anonymous endpoint that hands out bearer tokens.  You have to fetch and use the token.